# ListSelector for RecyclerView on touch free device (using onKey Listener)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a list selector for my `RecyclerView` grid on a touch free device. My implementation works fine but it requires `notifyItemChanged()` method which is not efficient performance wise. I have a grid with 100s of items so if i am scrolling fast (scrolling with a keyboard hence the onKey) the grid becomes distorted as lots of items are being updated. Is there a way to avoid this?

**Activity**

```
mRecyclerView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case Constants.KEYCODE_UP:
                        return moveSelection(lm, -1, true);

                    case Constants.KEYCODE_DOWN:
                        return moveSelection(lm, 1, true);
                }
            }
            return false;
         }   
});

public boolean moveSelection(RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm, int direction, boolean verticalMovement) {
   ...
   //just calculate the position to move to and pass it to selectedPosition
    return mAdapter.tryMoveSelection(lm, selectedPosition);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        mViewHolder = holder;

        holder.itemView.setSelected(mFocusedItem == position);
        ...
     }

public boolean tryMoveSelection(RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm, int selectedPosition) {
        notifyItemChanged(mFocusedItem);
        mFocusedItem = selectedPosition;
        notifyItemChanged(mFocusedItem);
        lm.scrollToPosition(mFocusedItem);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much better solution that doesn't involve `notifyItemChanged()` at all. What I do is extend the `RecyclerView` class and create two new methods:

- `clearSelection(int position)`
- `setSelection(int position)`

and call them in `tryMoveSelection` as follows:

```
boolean tryMoveSelection (RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm, int selectedPosition) {
    myRecyclerView.clearSelection(selectedPosition);
    mFocusedItem = selectedPosition;
    myRecyclerView.setSelection(mFocusedItem);
    lm.scrollToPosition(mFocusedItem);
    mRecyclerView.requestFocus();
    return true;
}
```

Details as follows:

```
public void setSelection(int position) {
   ViewHolder viewHolder = this.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    if (this.getChildCount() > 0 && viewHolder != null) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
        viewHolder.itemView.requestFocus();
    }
}

public void clearSelection(int position) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = this.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);
        viewHolder.itemView.clearFocus();
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of optimisations you could add to your code:

1. Don't call `notifyItemChanged()` when [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) is scrolling. There are couple of handy methods for that:

   - [`getScrollState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getScrollState()) - when the result is different than [`SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) then `RecyclerView` is scrolling.
   - [`hasPendingAdapterUpdates()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#hasPendingAdapterUpdates()) - that means, that `RecyclerView.RecyclerAdapter` has items to layout.
2. When the [`getScrollState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getScrollState()) is [`SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) then call `notifyItemChanged()`.
3. Adapter also has a couple of handy method to override:

   - [`void onViewAttachedToWindow (VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH)) - is called when view is about to be shown to the user.
   - [`void onViewDetachedFromWindow (VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH)) - the row is detached from view - free heavy resources here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a "payload" when you call "[notifyItemChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))". Payloads were designed just for these cases: when you only need to do a partial update and not run a full bind.

So, for example, you can notify your adapter with: `notifyItemChanged(1, "focusedItemChange")`, then in your adapter do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
        // Do a full bind
    } else if (payloads.contains("focusedItemChange")) {
        holder.itemView.setSelected(isFocusedPositon(position));
    }
}
```